# Javascript error from Expenses extension : https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/expenses

Tags: extension, javascript

Currently using CiviCRM Version 5.31 (Wordpress Version 5.5.3)

Network error appears when I click on Edit Expense or Delete Expense.

[image]

I tried the instructions listed on this website (Below link) and notice the following error

- https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=35850.0.html

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Below is the code in error when I clicked on "jquery.min.js:4"

g.send(b.hasContent&&b.data||null),c=function(a,d){var f,i,j;if(c&&(d||4===g.readyState))if(delete ec[h],c=void 0,g.onreadystatechange=n.noop,d)4!==g.readyState&&g.abort();else{j={},f=g.status,"string"==typeof g.responseText&&(j.text=g.responseText);try{i=g.statusText}catch(k){i=""}f||!b.isLocal||b.crossDomain?1223===f&&(f=204):f=j.text?200:404}j&&e(f,i,j,g.getAllResponseHeaders())},b.async?4===g.readyState?a.setTimeout(c):g.onreadystatechange=ec[h]=c:c()},abort:function(){c&&c(void 0,!0)}}}});function gc(){try{return new a.XMLHttpRequest}catch(b){}}function hc(){try{return new a.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(b){}}n.ajaxSetup({accepts:{script:"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"},contents:{script:/\b(?:java|ecma)script\b/},converters:{"text script":function(a){return n.globalEval(a),a}}}),n.ajaxPrefilter("script",function(a){void 0===a.cache&&(a.cache=!1),a.crossDomain&&(a.type="GET",a.global=!1)}),n.ajaxTransport("script",function(a){if(a.crossDomain){var b,c=d.head||n("head")[0]||d.documentElement;return{send:function(e,f){b=d.createElement("script"),b.async=!0,a.scriptCharset&&(b.charset=a.scriptCharset),b.src=a.url,b.onload=b.onreadystatechange=function(a,c){(c||!b.readyState||/loaded|complete/.test(b.readyState))&&(b.onload=b.onreadystatechange=null,b.parentNode&&b.parentNode.removeChild(b),b=null,c||f(200,"success"))},c.insertBefore(b,c.firstChild)},abort:function(){b&&b.onload(void 0,!0)}}}});var ic=[],jc=/(=)?(?=&|$)|??/;n.ajaxSetup({jsonp:"callback",jsonpCallback:function(){var a=ic.pop()||n.expando+"_"+Db++;return this[a]=!0,a}}),n.ajaxPrefilter("json jsonp",function(b,c,d){var e,f,g,h=!1!==b.jsonp&&(jc.test(b.url)?"url":"string"==typeof b.data&&0===(b.contentType||"").indexOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")&&jc.test(b.data)&&"data");if(h||"jsonp"===b.dataTypes[0])return e=b.jsonpCallback=n.isFunction(b.jsonpCallback)?b.jsonpCallback():b.jsonpCallback,h?b[h]=b[h].replace(jc,"$1"+e):!1!==b.jsonp&&(b.url+=(Eb.test(b.url)?"&":"?")+b.jsonp+"="+e),b.converters["script json"]=function(){return g||n.error(e+" was not called"),g[0]},b.dataTypes[0]="json",f=a[e],a[e]=function(){g=arguments},d.always(function(){void 0===f?n(a).removeProp(e):a[e]=f,b[e]&&(b.jsonpCallback=c.jsonpCallback,ic.push(e)),g&&n.isFunction(f)&&f(g[0]),g=f=void 0}),"script"}),n.parseHTML=function(a,b,c){if(!a||"string"!=typeof a)return null;"boolean"==typeof b&&(c=b,b=!1),b=b||d;var e=x.exec(a),f=!c&&[];return e?[b.createElement(e[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gH0s.png))]:(e=ia([a],b,f),f&&f.length&&n(f).remove(),n.merge([],e.childNodes))};var kc=n.fn.load;n.fn.load=function(a,b,c){if("string"!=typeof a&&kc)return kc.apply(this,arguments);var d,e,f,g=this,h=a.indexOf(" ");return h>-1&&(d=n.trim(a.slice(h,a.length)),a=a.slice(0,h)),n.isFunction(b)?(c=b,b=void 0):b&&"object"==typeof b&&(e="POST"),g.length>0&&n.ajax({url:a,type:e||"GET",dataType:"html",data:b}).done(function(a){f=arguments,g.html(d?n("").append(n.parseHTML(a)).find(d):a)}).always(c&&function(a,b){g.each(function(){c.apply(this,f||[a.responseText,b,a])})}),this},n.each(["ajaxStart","ajaxStop","ajaxComplete","ajaxError","ajaxSuccess","ajaxSend"],function(a,b){n.fn[b]=function(a){return this.on(b,a)}}),n.expr.filters.animated=function(a){return n.grep(n.timers,function(b){return a===b.elem}).length};function lc(a){return n.isWindow(a)?a:9===a.nodeType&&(a.defaultView||a.parentWindow)}n.offset={setOffset:function(a,b,c){var d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k=n.css(a,"position"),l=n(a),m={};"static"===k&&(a.style.position="relative"),h=l.offset(),f=n.css(a,"top"),i=n.css(a,"left"),j=("absolute"===k||"fixed"===k)&&n.inArray("auto",[f,i])>-1,j?(d=l.position(),g=d.top,e=d.left):(g=parseFloat(f)||0,e=parseFloat(i)||0),n.isFunction(b)&&(b=b.call(a,c,n.extend({},h))),null!=b.top&&(m.top=b.top-h.top+g),null!=b.left&&(m.left=b.left-h.left+e),"using"in b?b.using.call(a,m):l.css(m)}},n.fn.extend({offset:function(a){if(arguments.length)return void 0===a?this:this.each(function(b){n.offset.setOffset(this,a,b)});var b,c,d={top:0,left:0},e=this[0],f=e&&e.ownerDocument;if(f)return b=f.documentElement,n.contains(b,e)?(void 0!==e.getBoundingClientRect&&(d=e.getBoundingClientRect()),c=lc(f),{top:d.top+(c.pageYOffset||b.scrollTop)-(b.clientTop||0),left:d.left+(c.pageXOffset||b.scrollLeft)-(b.clientLeft||0)}):d},position:function(){if(this[0]){var a,b,c={top:0,left:0},d=this[0];return"fixed"===n.css(d,"position")?b=d.getBoundingClientRect():(a=this.offsetParent(),b=this.offset(),n.nodeName(a[0],"html")||(c=a.offset()),c.top+=n.css(a[0],"borderTopWidth",!0),c.left+=n.css(a[0],"borderLeftWidth",!0)),{top:b.top-c.top-n.css(d,"marginTop",!0),left:b.left-c.left-n.css(d,"marginLeft",!0)}}},offsetParent:function(){return this.map(function(){var a=this.offsetParent;while(a&&!n.nodeName(a,"html")&&"static"===n.css(a,"position"))a=a.offsetParent;return a||Pa})}}),n.each({scrollLeft:"pageXOffset",scrollTop:"pageYOffset"},function(a,b){var c=/Y/.test(b);n.fn[a]=function(d){return X(this,function(a,d,e){var f=lc(a);if(void 0===e)return f?b in f?f[b]:f.document.documentElement[d]:a[d];f?f.scrollTo(c?n(f).scrollLeft():e,c?e:n(f).scrollTop()):a[d]=e},a,d,arguments.length,null)}}),n.each(["top","left"],function(a,b){n.cssHooks[b]=Ta(l.pixelPosition,function(a,c){if(c)return c=Ra(a,b),Na.test(c)?n(a).position()[b]+"px":c})}),n.each({Height:"height",Width:"width"},function(a,b){n.each({padding:"inner"+a,content:b,"":"outer"+a},function(c,d){n.fn[d]=function(d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(!0===d||!0===e?"margin":"border")

Comment: Welcome to SE!  It's hard to read those console errors but it looks like it is trying to fetch from an IP address.  Is that your server? Has your server changed IP since it was last working?

Comment: Yes hard to read! But also it says Internal Server Error so I would check the web server log to see the real error, e.g. apache/nginx error log.

Comment: Yes there is a change in my server IP address but i have not encounter other problems arising from the change of IP address. I have pasted the code in the question, do you know what is issue? Thank you Aidan and Demerit for the quick response. Appreciate it!